# How Do I Remove The Border Of An Input

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AGDZ.jpg)

I have been trying to create a very simple login page. Around these inputs, as you can see, there are black borders. My question is, how do I remove that border?

Comment: You'll need to add a [mcve] to your question. We don't debug images

Comment: Try to post some of your code here and explain better what you need.

Comment: Probably disable with: `:focus { outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 0; outline-width: 0 } /* for Edge 2020 */
`, but cannot be sure without some [reprex]....

Answer (score 1):

is not a border but an accessibility border from chrome.
You could try disabling this flag: `chrome://flags/#form-controls-refresh` 
Apparantly the 83+ version of chrome changed how forms are rendered / handled.

Comment: I have disabled it.But now the border is light blue.Is there any other way?

Comment: Take a look to @Jason answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is the new Google Chrome update. I encountered it the other day. Just add `outline: none;` to the element:

```css
#testInput {
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 25px;
  width: 225px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<input id="testInput" type="text" placeholder="If you click here, no border is shown!" />
```

You could also try disabling this flag: `chrome://flags/#form-controls-refresh`. That will change the colour of the outline to a light-blue, which "was" default before Google Changed the option. But, if you are trying to make a website for the public, the first option would be better, as not everyone has disabled that flag. Hope this helps!

**Edit:** This does not work on `<select>` and `<option>` elements for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following stylization:

```
button {
   border: none;
}

button:checked {
   border: none;
}
```

otherwise, the problem may be a feature of the browser you are using.

I hope to help and, if possible, add the code snippet used.